# Have been unable to put my personal information on my map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have been working on a project recently. But after finishing it I am trying to put my name, date and some other information on the map without using text on insert.

Comment: Are you using Layouts? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-page-layouts.htm

Comment: I am not sure why you wouldn't want to use the insert text, but another option would be to create an image (in paint or a tool like it) of the information that you want, then insert the image onto the map canvas, and then size it move it how you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your map is in layout view, there's an option of "dynamic text" under insert tab. If not in layout view then convert from data to layout view first to get this option active.[image]